# SVG object not respecting boundary when dragging

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm am working on some JavaScipt code that is intended to allow a user to drag an SVG circle inside of one of many SVG rectangles. Once the SVG circle is placed inside a rectangle it can be dragged around the inside of that rectangle, but it should not be able to exit the rectangle. My code seems to initially respect the boundary of the rectangle, but I can still push it past the boundary with little effort. I originally had this somewhat working, but the movement was not very smooth at all. When I improve the smoothness of the drag, the boundary is not respected anymore. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I seem to be going in circles.

```js
    var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    var circle = document.getElementById('myCircle');
    var circleRadius = circle.getAttribute('r');
    var rect1 = {x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100};
    var rect2 = {x: 200, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100};
    var rect3 = {x: 350, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100};
    var dragging = false;
    var offset = {x: 0, y: 0};

    // add event listeners to the circle
    svg.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
    svg.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
    svg.addEventListener('mouseup', endDrag);
    svg.addEventListener('mouseleave', endDrag);
    svg.addEventListener('touchstart', startDrag);
    svg.addEventListener('touchmove', drag);
    svg.addEventListener('touchend', endDrag);
    svg.addEventListener('touchleave', endDrag);
    svg.addEventListener('touchcancel', endDrag);

    function startDrag(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        dragging = true;
        var clientX, clientY;
        if (event.type === 'touchstart') {
            clientX = event.touches[0].clientX;
            clientY = event.touches[0].clientY;
        } else {
            clientX = event.clientX;
            clientY = event.clientY;
        }
        var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
        pt.x = clientX;
        pt.y = clientY;
        var svgP = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
        offset.x = svgP.x - parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cx'));
        offset.y = svgP.y - parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cy'));
    }

    function drag(event) {
        if (dragging) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var clientX, clientY;
            if (event.type === 'touchmove') {
                clientX = event.touches[0].clientX;
                clientY = event.touches[0].clientY;
            } else {
                clientX = event.clientX;
                clientY = event.clientY;
            }
            var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
            pt.x = clientX;
            pt.y = clientY;
            var svgP = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());

            var x = svgP.x - offset.x;
            var y = svgP.y - offset.y;

            // check if the circle is inside any of the rectangles
            var rect = getRectContainingPoint(x, y);
            if (rect) {
                // check if the circle is inside the rectangle
            var rectLeft = rect.x + circleRadius / 2;
            var rectRight = rect.x + rect.width - circleRadius / 2;
            var rectTop = rect.y + circleRadius / 2;
            var rectBottom = rect.y + rect.height - circleRadius / 2;
                            if (x < rectLeft) {
                x = rectLeft;
                offset.x = svgP.x - parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cx'));
            } else if (x > rectRight) {
                x = rectRight;
                offset.x = svgP.x - parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cx'));
            }
            if (y < rectTop) {
                y = rectTop;
                offset.y = svgP.y - parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cy'));
            } else if (y > rectBottom) {
                y = rectBottom;
                offset.y = svgP.y - parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cy'));
            }

            // update the circle position and radius
            circle.setAttribute('cx', x);
            circle.setAttribute('cy', y);
            if (circle.getAttribute('r') != circleRadius / 2) {
                circle.setAttribute('r', circleRadius / 2);
            }
        } else {
            // update the circle position and radius
            circle.setAttribute('cx', x);
            circle.setAttribute('cy', y);
            if (circle.getAttribute('r') != circleRadius * 2 && getRectContainingPoint(circle.getAttribute('cx'), circle.getAttribute('cy'))) {
                circle.setAttribute('r', circleRadius * 2);
            }
        }
    }
}

function endDrag(event) {
    dragging = false;
}

function getRectContainingPoint(x, y) {
    if (x >= rect1.x && x <= rect1.x + rect1.width && y >= rect1.y && y <= rect1.y + rect1.height) {
        return rect1;
    } else if (x >= rect2.x && x <= rect2.x + rect2.width && y >= rect2.y && y <= rect2.y + rect2.height) {
        return rect2;
    } else if (x >= rect3.x && x <= rect3.x + rect3.width && y >= rect3.y && y <= rect3.y + rect3.height) {
        return rect3;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```css
rect {
  fill         : lightblue;
  stroke       : black;
  stroke-width : 2;
}

circle {
  fill         : red;
  stroke       : black;
  stroke-width : 2;
  cursor       : move;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="200" y="50" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="350" y="50" width="100" height="100"/>
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="30" id="myCircle"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: your SVG has no viewbox. it seems impossible to me that anything could be really functional without.

Comment: and indeed, this completely distorts your calculations of offsets between those of the mouse and the svg graphics

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I added a viewbox as suggested and changed the functions to work off of the current transformation matrix . I also implemented "touch" support. It's working a little better, but I can still force the circle outside of the rectangles with fast mouse movements. Not sure if it has something to do with how often the listeners are firing.

Comment: the first problem here is that you seem to not have realized that the svg language is vectorial where all the coordinates are abstract values, they are not pixels values.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that.
But for real, you must use the [Drag & Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)

```js
const 
  mySvg  = document.querySelector('#my-svg')
, Ball   = mySvg.querySelector('circle')
, rects  = [...mySvg.querySelectorAll('rect')].map( ElmX =>
    { 
    let { x, y, width, height } = ElmX.getBBox();
    return {x, y, xE: x + width, yE: y + height, rectElm: ElmX }
    })
, mouseSVG = (()=>
    {
    const 
      vb  = mySvg.viewBox.baseVal
    , bcr = mySvg.getBoundingClientRect()
    , wr  = bcr.width / vb.width    // width ratio
    , hr  = bcr.height / vb.height  // height ration 
    , x0  = bcr.left - (vb.x * wr)  // svg X 0 pixel page position
    , y0  = bcr.top  - (vb.y * hr)  // svg Y 0 pixel page position
      ;
    return ({pageX,pageY}) => ({mX: Math.round((pageX - x0) / wr),mY: Math.round((pageY - y0) / hr) });
    })()
, status = 
    { onGrab     : false  // ball follow cursor...
    , freeBall   : true   // no box caught her !
    , rectTarget : null
    , mzX        : 0      // mouse pageX Position on grab start
    , mzY        : 0      // mouse pageX Position on grab start
    , btX        : 0      // ball translation X
    , btY        : 0      // ball translation Y
    , bcX        : Ball.cx.baseVal.value
    , bcY        : Ball.cy.baseVal.value
    }
, inBox = {}
  ;
Ball.onmousedown  = e =>
  {
  Ball.classList.add('grabMove');
  mySvg.classList.add('grabMove');
  let { mX, mY } = mouseSVG(e);
  status.onGrab  = true;
  status.mzX     = mX - status.btX;
  status.mzY     = mY - status.btY;
  }
mySvg.onmousemove = mousemoveFree;
mySvg.onmouseup   = endGrabFree;
mySvg.onmouseout  = endGrabFree;

function mousemoveFree(e)
  {
  if ( status.onGrab )
    {
    let {mX,mY} = mouseSVG(e);
    status.btX  =  mX - status.mzX;
    status.btY  =  mY - status.mzY;

    Ball.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${status.btX},${status.btY})`);

    let x = rects.find(r=>r.x<mX && mX<r.xE && r.y<mY && mY<r.yE)?.rectElm;
    if ( !!x )
      {
      if (x !== status.rectTarget) x.setAttribute('stroke','yellow'); 
      }
    else if (!!status.rectTarget ) status.rectTarget.setAttribute('stroke','black');
    status.rectTarget = x;
    }
  }  
function mouseMoveBox(e)
  {
  if ( status.onGrab )
    {
    let {mX,mY} = mouseSVG(e);

    if (inBox.x < mX && mX < inBox.xE && inBox.y < mY && mY < inBox.yE )
      {
      status.btX  =  mX - status.mzX;
      status.btY  =  mY - status.mzY;
      let      
        ball_x = status.bcX + status.btX
      , ball_y = status.bcY + status.btY
        ;
      Ball.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${status.btX},${status.btY})`);
      }
    else
      {
      endGrabBox();
      }
    }  
  }
function endGrabFree(e)
  {
  Ball.classList.remove('grabMove');
  mySvg.classList.remove('grabMove');
  status.onGrab = false;

  if (!!status.rectTarget && status.freeBall )
    {
    mySvg.onmousemove = mouseMoveBox;
    mySvg.onmouseup   = endGrabBox;
    mySvg.onmouseout  = endGrabBox;

    status.freeBall = false;
    status.rectTarget.setAttribute('stroke','black');

    let      
      ball_x                  = status.bcX + status.btX
    , ball_y                  = status.bcY + status.btY
    , ball_r                  = Ball.r.baseVal.value  / 2
    , { x, y, width, height } = status.rectTarget.getBBox()
    , xE =  x + width 
    , yE =  y + height
      ;
    Object.assign( inBox, { x, y, xE, yE, ball_r } ) 
 
    Ball.r.baseVal.value = ball_r;

    Ball.setAttribute('transform', '');
    ball_x = Math.max(  x + ball_r, ball_x );
    ball_y = Math.max(  y + ball_r, ball_y );
    ball_x = Math.min( xE - ball_r, ball_x );
    ball_y = Math.min( yE - ball_r, ball_y );
    status.btX = 0;
    status.btY = 0;

    Ball.cx.baseVal.value = status.bcX = ball_x;
    Ball.cy.baseVal.value = status.bcY = ball_y;
    }
  }
function endGrabBox(e)
  {
  if (!status.onGrab)
    return;

  Ball.classList.remove('grabMove');
  mySvg.classList.remove('grabMove');
  status.onGrab = false;
 
  let      
    ball_x = status.bcX + status.btX
  , ball_y = status.bcY + status.btY
    ;
  ball_x = Math.max(  inBox.x + inBox.ball_r, ball_x );
  ball_y = Math.max(  inBox.y + inBox.ball_r, ball_y );
  ball_x = Math.min( inBox.xE - inBox.ball_r, ball_x );
  ball_y = Math.min( inBox.yE - inBox.ball_r, ball_y );

  status.btX = 0;
  status.btY = 0;

  Ball.setAttribute('transform', '');

  Ball.cx.baseVal.value = status.bcX = ball_x;
  Ball.cy.baseVal.value = status.bcY = ball_y;
  }
```

```css
svg {
  margin     : 1rem;
  width      : 900px;  /* 1.5 x bigger. */
  height     : 750px;  /* 1.5 x bigger. */
  background : #021d6e;
  }
rect {
  fill         : lightblue;
  stroke-width : 2;
  }
circle {
  fill         : red;
  stroke       : black;
  stroke-width : 2;
  cursor       : grab;
  }
circle.grabMove,
svg.grabMove {
  cursor       : grabbing !important;
  }
```

```html
<svg id="my-svg" viewBox="-50 -100 600 500"> 
  <rect x="50"  y="50" width="100" height="100" stroke="black"/>
  <rect x="200" y="50" width="100" height="100" stroke="black"/>
  <rect x="350" y="50" width="100" height="100" stroke="black"/>
  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="30" transform="" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Works pretty well. I will play around with trying to add touch support. I will also check out the drag and drop API you suggested. Thx

Comment: @BillFiore   I spent a lot of time there, and I was hoping that you would at least validate my answer...

Comment: Sorry about that, I had created this post under a new account (couldn't find my old login) and it wouldn't let me cast a vote due to my reputation being under 15. I will try to find my old login, but do appreciate the time spent.